# Error: invalid_scope google read contact

Tags: google-api

What is the reason for this error?
How can I fix this?

```
Error: invalid_scope

This app hasn't been verified to access: {invalid = [https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/]} Please contact the developer for assistance. Are you the developer? If this project needs these scopes, sign in to an account with access to edit your project and try again. If not, contact the developer for help.
```

Comment: This app hasn't been verified to access: {invalid = [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have enhanced our risk assessment for new web applications that
>   request user data. Based on this risk assessment, some web
>   applications will require a manual review before users can approve
>   data permissions. Until the review is complete, unverified apps will
>   display an error message instead of the permissions consent page.
>
> See our earlier blog post on accessing user data, which outlines your
>   responsibility when requesting access to user data from your
>   application. Our teams will continue our constant efforts to support a
>   powerful, useful developer ecosystem that keeps users and their data
>   safe.

Sources:

- https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7394288
- https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Comment: I use the https protocol, but because this is?